# How to extract information from one column to create a new column in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of excel files, I want to combine, but in a first step, I'm trying to manipulate the files.
My data more or less looks like this:

| session | type | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| parliament: 12 |  |  |
| 1 | standing | member |
| 1 | standing | member |
| parliament: 13 |  |  |
| 1 | standing | member |
| 2 | standing | member |

Now, what I'm trying to do, is to add a new column containing the parliament information from the session column, while at the same time keeping all the other information as it is. So my final excel should look like this:

| session | type | role | parliament |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | standing | member | 12 |
| 1 | standing | member | 12 |
| 1 | standing | member | 13 |
| 2 | standing | member | 13 |

Can you guys please help me understanding how to solve this?

EDIT:
Here' a slice of my data in dictionary form

```
{'Session': {0: 'Parliament: 28', 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'Composition': {0: nan, 1: 'Senate', 2: 'Senate', 3: 'Senate', 4: 'Senate'},
 'Type': {0: nan, 1: 'Standing', 2: 'Standing', 3: 'Standing', 4: 'Standing'},
 'Role': {0: nan, 1: 'Chair', 2: 'Member', 3: 'Member', 4: 'Member'},
 'Organization': {0: nan,
  1: 'Committee of Selection',
  2: 'Standing Committee on Banking and Commerce',
  3: 'Standing Committee on Finance',
  4: 'Standing Committee on Immigration and Labour'},
 'Political Affiliation': {0: nan,
  1: 'Liberal Party of Canada',
  2: 'Liberal Party of Canada',
  3: 'Liberal Party of Canada',
  4: 'Liberal Party of Canada'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df[['txt','parliament']]=df['Session'].str.split(':', expand=True).ffill()
df=df[~df['Type'].isnull()]
df.drop(columns='txt')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your solution doesn't give me any rows back, i.e. the data frame now is empty for some reason

Comment: @futur3boy  well, i use the data from the question and the result is based off of it. Perhaps, you you put the data as a code, to create the starting DF.  that is the only difference b/w our respective results. follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, sorry, I thought, my data example would suffice, but apparently it doesn't. I added an excerpt of my real data to the edit of my post

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` each partliament group using `cumsum()`, and then just restructure the data in the `apply` function to match the final output you want:

```
(df.groupby(df.session.str.contains('parliament').cumsum())
   .apply(lambda s: s[1:].assign(parliament=s.head(1).session.item().strip('parliament: ')))
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
  session      type    role parliament
0       1  standing  member         12
1       1  standing  member         12
2       1  standing  member         13
3       2  standing  member         13
```

Comment: when I try your suggestion, I get the following error message:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'session'

Comment: @futur3boy This means you don;t have a column named `session`. Just replace `df.session` with whatever your column name is.

Comment: ohh, I see, though, your code changes data frame in a way such that now all column contain NaNs, except the session (this columns also doesn't contain the original values) and parliament columns.

Comment: Well, then change your post because with the [mcve] you provided, it works just fine :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner and really just trying to understand this, my original data frame looks like the example one in this post (though, having a few more rows and unimportant columns). I don't know what else, might be different, that changes the results so drastically?

Comment: @futur3boy rather than posting the dataframe in raw text, slice a small part of your `df` and post the output of the` to_dict()` method. For example, `df.head(5).to_dict()`. That way, we can copy the dict and work with the exact same data.

Comment: I added the output in the edit of my post

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the number after *parliament:* then front fill the value:

```
out = (df[~df['session'].str.startswith('parliament')]
           .join(df['session'].str.extract(r':\s(?P<parliament>\d+)').ffill()))
print(out)

# Output
  session      type    role parliament
1       1  standing  member         12
2       1  standing  member         12
4       1  standing  member         13
5       2  standing  member         13
```

Comment: your suggestion gives me this error message:
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'